# Me sale el error el constructor no puede aplicarse a tipos dados

Tags: java

```
public class testPunto2D {
    public static float rand(float t){
        return (float) Math.random()*t;
    }
   
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Punto2D p1 = new Punto2D(), p2 = new Punto2D();
        int top = 200;
        
        p1.setXY(rand(top),rand(top));
        p2.setXY(rand(top),rand(top));
        System.out.printf("Entre los puntos %s y %s hay una distancia de %4.2f\n",
            p1.toString(), p2.toString(), p1.distance(p2));
    }
}
```

Me sale específicamente  así: constructor cannot be applied to given types actual and formal argument lists differ in length o el constructor no puede aplicarse a tipos dados las listas de argumentos reales y formales difieren en longitud

rror: constructor Punto2D in class Punto2D cannot be applied to given types;
Punto2D p1 = new Punto2D(), p2 = new Punto2D();
^
required: float,float
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: tu método *rand* requiere un parámetro de tipo *float* y tu le estas pasando top que es de tipo *int*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu clase Punto2D, tienes un constructor que contiene 2 floats como parámetros:

```
Punto2D(float x, float y){
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}
```

agrega el constructor sin parámetros:

```
Punto2D(){}
```

Y con eso se debe resolver tu problema.

Saludos

Comment: Hola amigo, muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Eso fue lo que hice y funciono!

Answer (score 0):

El código que nos compartes es inútil. La clase `testPunto2D` sirve para probar `Punto2D`. De modo que es esa la clase que importa. Sin su código o, por lo menos, el archivo `Punto2D.class` no es posible saber cuál es el problema que tienes. Un abrazo.